# How to limit download/upload speed for specific users?

Tags: networking, server, internet, bandwidth, resource-limiting

I want to setup an ubuntu server in which some users are limited to a specific download/upload speed.Is it possible?

I know about Wondershaper, Trickle or similar tools but I don't want to limit programs or an interface bandwidth because the machine will have different kind of users.

A solution for limiting speed for a group or specific users would be great.

Answer (score 1):

*iptables* with *tc*?  Then again I think I remember pfSense (yeah it's not Ubuntu :/ ), used for traffic shaping, among its many roles, in a small office I used to work for. Since we were in a LAN, everything passes through pfSense. Each user is considered as 1 IP.

What kind of setup are you having, thin clients connected to one server?

Comment: Thanks.Any tutorial to do this with iptables and tc?It's not in a network.I want to provide some shell accounts for users.